# DeferredResult with ajax request with two request

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I´m trying to use DeferredResult with an ajax request, but when I return the result my ajax request keeps waiting for response.

Here the client that make the long polling request

```
    (function poll() {
var SUCCESS = 1;
var tenantName = $("#tenantName").val();
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "url.do?subStep=" + subStep + "&tenantId=" + tenantName,
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response)
        if (response.status === SUCCESS) {
            bootbox.dialog({
                size:"small",
                message: "<div class='col-xs-offset-4'>" +
                "<i class='fa fa-user'> Page has been modify by " + response.payload + " " +
                "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='reload()'>reload</a>" +
                "</i>" +
                "</div>"
            });
        }
    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 60000
});
})();
```

Here my controller where I make a long polling request by Ajax every 30 seconds.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<JsonEntity> getSubStepStatus(@RequestParam("subStep") String subStep,
                                                   @RequestParam("tenantId") String tenantId) {
    if (tenantsInStep.get(subStep) == null) {
        initializeTenantsInStep(subStep);
    }
    if(!tenantsInStep.get(subStep).contains(tenantId)){
        tenantsInStep.get(subStep).add(tenantId);
    }
    DeferredResult<JsonEntity> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>();
    tenantsDeferredInStep.put(tenantId, deferredResult);
    return deferredResult;
}
```

And then when my application detect a POST/PUT ajax request invoke a request to this method of my controller that release the DeferredResults.

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/setModification", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public final Integer setModification(@RequestParam("subStep") String subStep,
                                     @RequestParam("tenantId") String tenantId) {
    for (String tenantInStepId : tenantsInStep.get(subStep)) {
        if (!tenantId.equals(tenantInStepId)) {
            JsonEntity<String> jsonEntity = new JsonEntity();
            jsonEntity.setPayload(tenantId);
            jsonEntity.setStatus(FeedbackActions.SUCCESS.getCode());
            DeferredResult<JsonEntity> jsonEntityDeferredResult = tenantsDeferredInStep.get(tenantId);
            tenantsInStep.remove(tenantInStepId);
            jsonEntityDeferredResult.setResult(jsonEntity);
        }
    }
    return FeedbackActions.SUCCESS.getCode();
}
```

This example has been done by two user with two browser to achieve this, but the first client that create the deferredResult dont receive the result when the second client invoke the deferredResult.setResult(bla), no alert on ajax code is invoked.

I´m doing something wrong?, I add the

```
     <task:annotation-driven/>
```

And the

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/webmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
```

In my applicationContext and web.xml configuration

As an extra information I´m using on my local test Jetty
Regards.

Comment: can you please add response you get in  response variable ?

Comment: what you get when you alert(response) ??

Comment: If you read the post I say that the response never arrive to the client 1 that make the long polling request